# Netbeans: project won't start all of a sudden - Glassfish problems?

Tags: deployment, netbeans, glassfish

I am a first time user of Netbeans, and was just playing around. I followed a very basic tutorial, and when I first ran the project, it opened up my browser (Chrome) and displayed what it should display.

The next day, I want to show it to my buddies, but the project won't start.

The project tab shows the following:

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server 3.1.2
```

and the other tab "Java DB Database Process" gives me the following:

```
Wed May 23 19:52:45 CEST 2012 : Sicherheitsmanager mit einfacher Server-Sicherheitsrichtlinie installiert.
Wed May 23 19:52:46 CEST 2012 : Apache Derby Network Server 10.8.1.2 - (1095077) wurde gestartet und ist bereit, Verbindungen am Port 1527 zu akzeptieren.
```

(the last line translates to "Server was started and is ready to accept connections in port 1527")

The only thing that was different when I tried it was the fact that I was in a public wireless net in University, and not at home. Windows Firewall asked me, if I wanted to grant permission, and I said "Yes"

So basically Netbeans tells me that my project is currently in the process of being started, but nothing happens for ages.

Any ideas what I could possibly have done wrong? I googled the heck out of it, but found nothing.

EDIT: After 20 minutes I get a timeout and a message that the server couldn't be started. I am clueless...

Comment: In your glassfish folder (you'll have to drill in a bit) is a server.log file. What does it say?

Comment: I got frustrated and uninstalled the whole thing and downgraded to an older version, then it worked again. Still curious as to why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 0):

The different network configuration can indeed be a reason for this issue.

You could verify this by either checking the server.log under:

> *glassfish-install-dir/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.log*

Scroll down to the last log entry before server start stopped.

Or you can start your server manually in verbose mode. Then you will see all log messages in the console:

Open a console window and switch to the following directory:

> *glassfish-install-dir/bin*

Then enter the following command:

> asadmin start-domain --verbose=true